# Complex MySQL Fetch Relation and Conditions from Table to Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables that I want to fetch data from one another with a specific condition.

Table 1: Customers

```
-----------------------------
ID | Name | lastCountry | blf
1  | Jack | NONE        | 1
2  | Idan | NONE        | 1
3  | Kint | Thailand    | 0
----------------------------
```

Table 2: Travels

```
----------------------------
id | userID | fromCountry | toCountry |  startTime  | endTime
1  |   1    | Canada      | Myanmar   |  2015-29-05 | 2015-31-07
2  |   2    | Australia   | Poland    |  2015-29-05 | 2015-31-06
----------------------------
```

How do I make a list that says Myanmar (1), Thailand (1), Poland (1)?

Notice that in the table **travels**, the **toCountry** is Myanmar and Poland. Both records have a startTime<=CURDATE() and endTime>=CURDATE(). 
The only way for a country to be shown is when someone is **currently** travelling in that country from the startTime and endTime. Also, the customers table says, Kint is blf=0 and lastCountry is Thailand. This means, Kint's currently in Thailand, but he doesn't have a record in the travels (blf=0). However, Kint's travel to Thailand is counted as 1.

How do I make a list that says Myanmar (1), Thailand (1) and Poland (1). A PHP code that generates all the countries currently being visited with corresponding amount of visitors on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you use the union clause to join the results of the two tables counting the number found:

```
SELECT count(*) as lastCountryCount, lastCountry 
FROM Customers 
WHERE blf=1
GROUP BY lastCountry
UNION
SELECT count(*) as toCountryCount, toCountry 
FROM Travels
GROUP BY toCountry
```

then process the array to show the counts for each country.